# Regular expression for counting sentences in the text escaping the dot in email adress

Tags: java, regex

I have a sentence like **My email address is xxxx@xxx.xxx.**

My java regExp is "**.+?[\.\?\!]+**"
This regExp sees two sentences **My email address is xxxx@xxx.** and **xxx.**

How do i modify my regExp so it wouldn't count email dots as a sentence end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reliably. Consider this example:

```
My email is someone@subdomain.com.hi!
```

Is the email `someone@subdomain.com.hi` or just `someone@subdomain.com`?

The only thing you can do is, if your texts are written by literate people, detect a sentence ending as one of `.`, `?`, `!` (or maybe other) **plus some space**.

---

And now to ruin all hope. What about this text? How many sentences does it have?

> He shouted "Freeze!", and then pulled
>   out his gun.

Answer (score 0):

With proper writing, that is - leaving space after each punctuation mark, you can look for each `\.\s`

Answer (score 0):

Decide what constitutes the end of a sentence, I'd probably use a '.' followed by space, tab or end of line.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not clear about your question.
If you are looking for a regular expression for detecting valid e-mail address use this.

```
pattern=/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

Example:

- name@gmail.co.uk
- name1.name2@gmail.com
- name1_name2@hotmail.co.ir
- etc.